# Number of continuous Segments?

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

An array A of N integers and one integer K. Count number of non-empty contiguous sub sequences of A, such that there are no bad pairs of integers in this sub segment. A pair (x, y) of integers is called bad if x is situated to the left of y in the array and x mod y = K?

Any better idea in less than or in theta(n^2) .
My tried Idea -
One solution is to store ( in map ) such number of pairs ( in O(n^2) ) then just iterate over all sub segments to further check it the pairs present or not in that segment and count it ....

Subsequences means :- If array have N elements than it have N*(N+1)/2 subsequences i.e 9,8,7,6,5 then we have [9];[8];[7];[6];[5];[9,8];[8,7];[7,6];[6,5];[9,8,7];[8,7,6];[7,6,5];[9,8,7,6];[8‌​,7,6,5];[9,8,7,6,5] are all subsequences :) –

Comment: Are the subsequences given or do you have to create them yourself?

Comment: Have to find for all sub sequences.... ( Mentioned above )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution written in Swift O(n).

The basic idea is to find the indexes of all bad pairs in the main sequence and then calculate the number of subsequences between those indices with your formula (splitting the bad pairs).

Imperative approach:

```
func numberOfSubsequences(array: [Int], k: Int) -> Int {
    // some spacial cases where you can return immediately
    if array.count <= 1 { return array.count }
    if array.count == 2 { return array[0] % array[1] == k ? 2 : 3 }

    var numberOfSubsequences = 0
    var startOfSubsequence = 0
    for i in 0..<array.count - 1 {
        // if a bad pair is found calculate the subsequence count between startOfSubsequence and i
        if array[i] % array[i+1] == k {
            let sequenceLength = i - startOfSubsequence + 1
            numberOfSubsequences += sequenceLength * (sequenceLength+1) / 2
            startOfSubsequence = i + 1
        }
    }
    // adding the remaining subsequence count from startOfSubsequence to the end of the array
    return numberOfSubsequences + (array.count - startOfSubsequence)*(array.count - startOfSubsequence + 1) / 2
}
```

a (more) functional approach using tail recursion:

```
func numberOfSubsequences2(array: [Int], k: Int) -> Int {
    if array.count <= 1 { return array.count }
    if array.count == 2 { return array[0] % array[1] == k ? 2 : 3 }

    // find first index of a bad pair
    var i = 0
    while (i + 1 < array.count) && (array[i] % array[i+1] != k) {
        i++
    }
    let count = (i+1)*(i+2)/2

    // recurse over the remaining array (tail) from i+1 to the end
    let tail = Array(array[i+1..<array.count])
    return count + numberOfSubsequences2(tail, k: k)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  check this solution

  #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

    int main() 
     {
     int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
     int a[n+1],i,j,ans=0;
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
cin>>a[i];
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        if(a[i]%a[j]==k){
            ans=ans+(n-j+1);
 break;
        }
    }
 }
    //if(k==0)ans=ans+n;
    cout<<n*(n+1)/2-ans;
// your code goes here
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Need answer in less complexity :)